# Why pygame is displaying text beneath the rect object?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm wondering why pygame is somehow rendering half of the text beneath the Rect objects. My end goal is to place the texts on top of the Rects, the color is not going to remain red, it's just there for debugging (It's white originally). I couldn't solve it on my own so I'm seeking help.

here is the current screen:

[image]

the code for drawing the line and rect objects:

```py
def draw(self, height, width):
        self._screen.fill((255,255,255))

        square_size = self.SCREEN_SIZE/9
        #draw lines
        for i in range(self.rows+1):
            thick = 4 if i % 3 == 0 else 1
            offset = i * square_size
            pygame.draw.line(self._screen, self.BLACK, (0, offset), (width, offset), width=thick)
            pygame.draw.line(self._screen, self.BLACK, (offset, 0), (offset, height), width=thick)

        for i in range(self.rows):
            for j in range(self.cols):
                self._board.init_square(motherboard[i][j], i, j)
                pygame.draw.rect(self._screen, (250,0,0), (i*square_size+3, j*square_size+3, square_size-4, square_size-4))
                
                # if self._board.board[i][j].value != 0:
                self.display_numbers(self._board.board[i][j].value, ((j*square_size), (i*square_size)+20))
```

and the `display_numbers()` function:

```py
 def display_numbers(self, value, position):
        # print(position)
        f_img = self._font.render(str(value), True, (0, 0, 0))
        self._screen.blit(f_img, position)
        # print(f"took {time.time()-t0} seconds to create font")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got `i` and `j` mixed up. When drawing the rectangles, `i` is the column and `j` is the row `(i*square_size+3, j*square_size+3, ...)`. However, when drawing the text, `j` is used for the columns and `i` for the rows (`((j*square_size), (i*square_size)+20)`). Swap `i` and `j` when drawing the rectangle:

<s>`pygame.draw.rect(self._screen, (250,0,0), (i*square_size+3, j*square_size+3, square_size-4, square_size-4))`</s>

```py
pygame.draw.rect(self._screen, (250,0,0), (j*square_size+3, i*square_size+3, square_size-4, square_size-4))
```

Note that if you swap `i` and `j`, the drawing order will be changed and some rectangles will be drawn over the previously drawn text. e.
g. For a 2x2 grid, the rectangles are drawn in the order *[(0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1)]*, but the text is drawn in the order *[(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1)]*. So at *(1, 0)* the text is covered by the rectangle because the rectangle is drawn later.

Comment: Is this some kind of flaw in pygame or something?

Comment: @arshiamohammadi No, it's just about the draw order. If you swap i` and `j`, the drawing order will be changed and some rectangles will be drawn over the previously drawn text.